# How is the phase velocity for a wave in a stringed instrument derived?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string, phase-velocity

I was searching on the internet for a formula relating velocity of wave and force of tension of a string (eg how the tension in a string instrument effects the velocity) and this formula keeps appearing.

$$
v_{\text{wave}} = \sqrt{\frac{F_{\text{tension}}}{{\rho}_{\text{linear}}}}
$$

What is the derivation of this formula as I can not find it online?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_vibration#Derivation

Comment: Probably, "P" is a misreading of Greek rho $\rho$ for linear density.

Comment: Just to note it, the above Wikipedia link answers this question, _but_ it's still neat to have such information added to StackExchange.  That said, I'm far too impatient to transcribe a derivation at the moment, so anyone who feels like it, please feel free!  (It's also 100% acceptable for askers to self-answer, if you care to review the derivation by explaining it to others, @Ditto.  The $\mathrm{\TeX}$ can largely be obtained by copy/pasting Wikipedia's $\mathrm{\TeX}$ expressions and wrapping them in `$`'s.)